# JDBC, transactions, rollback and background process threads

Tags: java, database, jdbc, transactions

I have an interesting problem with an application that I've inherited. The program is set up thus:

```
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
```

The program creates a huge transaction using JDBC, and rollback points are set using setSavePoint(mySavePoint). In the event of an error, the original coders intended for the transaction to rollback using transaction.rollBack(mySavePoint).

Unfortunately, the original coders created numerous background I/O processes that are vital as they allow other program clients to connect, send receive messages, start jobs etc. The problem is, these process are themselves calling transaction.commit(), so interrupting aforementioned "huge transaction". Hence, the background processes are causing rollback to fail in my "huge transaction" by making such commits. I can't turn these processes off because program behavior is dependent on these i/o process threads being able to write and commit to the database, rather than just to a log file.

Seems like a catch-22. What is my solution?

This is an old application which uses neither EJB nor Spring.

Comment: Isolate the background processes in another transaction scope... This way, they are not effected by what the users are doing. You must be having some Transaction manager which can be configured to do such a task...Or use multiple transaction managers.

Comment: Will it help you or shed some light  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17276_01/html/gsg_xml_txn/java/nestedtxn.html